# What's the Right Way to Store and Display Special Characters in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, html-entities

I'm parsing some HTML using Beautiful Soup, and occasionally the HTML it returns includes some special characters, such as `&mdash;` (long dash) and `&#174;` (register symbol).

I'm currently storing this html as a string in my db as is, and as a result when I display these variables in my templates the special characters appear as they do above. I've tried unescaping the characters using {{ variable|safe }} but that didn't work.

What is the right way to store, and then display, these types of special characters in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is here:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Entity Conversion

You'll want to use the convertEntities parameter and encode them as unicode.

The final line should be something like

```
decodedString=unicode(BeautifulStoneSoup(encodedString,convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

To display them again

```
"Your string with a long dash in it".encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

Comment: thanks, it turns out I was just adding the `|safe` filter in the wrong place. adding it to the right variable unescaped the string as expected.